# How do I let jQuery Validator use my pre-defined error element?

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm have a form set up which allows users to register with our mobile site. It has basic javascript validation using the jQuery validation plugin. However, our form submission script also performs validation. For this reason, if an error is caught the server sends an HTTP redirect back to the error page with some `$_GET` data.

When you load the form page, any errors found in the `$_GET` array are output to their respective field in a `<div class="error">`. This works great.

Since [jQuery validator](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) and our PHP script both perform the same validation, it makes sense that they should output errors to the same `div.error` field. This would also (theoretically) get rid of the error message once the field is validated.

However, if I change `errorElement: "div"` in jQuery validator, for some reason errors are not even mentioned. Changing it back to `em`, `label`, or `p` solves the issue. But if we change our initial element to any of those, it breaks again.

It must be a feature built in to the jQuery validation script, it will not output an error to an element that already exists unless it is created by the validator. How can I get around this?

Here is a fiddle demonstrating the issue, change `errorElement: "div"` to be of any kind of element and it will work.

http://jsfiddle.net/mDvHh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overwrite the `errorPlacement` instead of `errorElement` handler, e.g.:

```
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        element.next(".error").html(error);
    },
```

Also see [your updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mDvHh/1/).